# Get random data from database,

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, database

I have a little problem, I've got this database with these fields.

```
Table Data{
         ID
         Name,
         Text,
         Location,
         imagepath
         }
```

And now I want the put these values into my fields, the data is just strings.

```
<h3><!-- Text value here --> - <!-- Name value here --></h3>
<p> <!-- Location data here --> </p>
```

And I also got this JS script that generates new fields, when the user clicks on a button.

```
$('.Next').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 Slide.appendSlide('<!-- HTML DATA HERE   NAME AND TEXT & LOCATION VALUES -->')});
```

I want the ID to be random, and I don't want the user to get the same data twice.
How should i approach this? I've tried a getdata.php but failed.

**Thank you so much! Happy holidays!**

Comment: _"i don't want the user to get the same data twice"_ - Do you have an infinite amount of data in your database?

Comment: What's a "getdata.php"?

Comment: No of course not, but if the user click next i don't want the user to have the chance to get the same text again. Thanks.

Comment: Mtanti: It was a failed try to get data from the database. Dont know how is should approach this.

Comment: Well can we see what you tried to do in php? This can only be solved using PHP.

Comment: Also, do you want the ID to be random or just unique?

Comment: To prevent them from seeing the same profile again, you going to either have to use $_session, or a table to save user and id of page visited. What kind of numbers you looking at on this site?

Comment: Don't have the php code anymore, but i did try to src="getdata.php/id=2", didn't work.  And i want an unique ID, sorry for being unclear.

Comment: What kind of numbers? If you mean the length of the ID, it can be more than hundred or thousand.

Comment: What's your backend DB?  @Rob is right - you either need to save a list of ids in a session cookie/variable (probably an array), or stick them into a table.  What should happen when they've viewed all entries?  Repeat the exact same list?  Start over with a new set of entries?  Wait... does it have to be a different list for each user?  Could you just predefine a "random" list (or several), then just store what entry they're on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly i would look at saving the page id to $_session['visited']. Then each time they view a page append that to the session variable comma separated

> $_session['visited'] .= ",".$page_id;

Then your sql will be.

**EDITED**

Ok so let make this code safe

```
$ph = explode(",",$_session['visited']);
foreach($ph as $check){
  if (!isnumeric($check)){
    echo "Not numeric, possible injection";
    exit;
  }
}
$parmcount=count($ph);
$inclause=implode(',',array_fill(0,$parmcount,'?'))
$sql='SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID NOT IN (%s)';
$preparesql=sprintf($sql,$inclause);
$st=$db->prepare($preparesql);
$st->execute($parms);
```

Or alternative just save all viewed ids as an array in the first place.

Comment: Ah ok! I understand, but should i store the ID in session also? And compare ID with next ID or something similar?

Comment: Well the page id im refering to is the id of the row in the table. So each time they go to a new id it gets added to the $_session['visited'] which is then excluded from your sql statment

Comment: Oh, i think i understand what you mean. So when they slide to next text the id saves in the sesson?

Comment: Yeah correct. At the end of each tile sliding, add that id to the session, and the sql will exclude it the next time you slide.

Comment: Uh, there's one **HUGE** problem with this; the example query you're showing will essentially let anybody run SQL Injection trivially (this will be discovered by automated tools!).  The only/proper way to defend against SQL Injection is to use parameterized queries; unfortunately, there isn't any such thing as an "array" type as a parameter, so you can't easily supply a list of ids for an `IN` clause (as much as it would be nice...).  The current answer is _extremely_ dangerous and should **never** be used.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse has a very valid point here. What i would do is explode the $_session['visited'] by ',' check isnumeric() and then place into the statment. No hard to do and it should prevent SQL Injection

Comment: @Rob - you could at least add that to your answer, to make it safer.  Mind, I'd _still_ prefer to use parameterized queries, as otherwise somebody will come along and try to "optimize" the code and remove the explode/collapse...

Comment: Thanks guys! Would it work if i fetched all ids, then used array random and then got the data of that ID. Then saved that that ID in a session and compare next time ill fetch a new ID if that ID has been used before?

Comment: I suppose you could. The way i see you doing it is, selecting all ids into an array, randomising the array, then just take the first id from that array , unset it, then use it to select the row. Once again you would have to store that array as a $_SESSION var or write it to a table. if you choose $_session, remember they can be manipulated if your server has vulnerabilities (hense the whole comments of this answer). So use parameterized queries just to be extra safe.

Comment: Also note you will need to do a check to make sure the array is not empty. Once its empty, just select all the id into the array again and randomize. Alternative redirect them to say "hey you reached the end"

Comment: Would it work if istead of Session, that you store the "Used IDs" in a array itself and just run trough a foreach with the new ID?

Comment: You can try, it depends on how you plan to do it. The way i see it, the slide is "loading a new page", and if that is the case your array will be either empty, or repopulated on each slide giving you the risk of displaying the same slide again. I'll stick to my original answer and say use $_session